# AngularJS: Removing the "#" with history.pushState()

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs, .htaccess, pushstate

I'm trying to prettify the urls within my Angularjs application, but I've had limited success -- I can reach the `"/"` route, but that's it, `"/about"` is unreachable.

> Note: The project is located at (`localhost/myngapp`).

### index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <base href="myngapp">
    <script  type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.12/angular.js"></script>
    <script  type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.12/angular-route.js"></script> 
    <script  type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/myngapp/public/js/app.js"></script>   
</head>

<body data-ng-app="demoApp">
    <div data-ng-view></div>
</body>

</html>
```

### app.js

```
angular.module('demoApp', ['ngRoute'])
    .config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) { 
        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true); 
        $routeProvider
             .when('/', {
                 controller: 'homeCtrl',
                templateUrl: 'home.html'
             })         
             .when('/about', {
                 controller: 'aboutCtrl',
                 templateUrl: 'about.html'
             })     
            .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });       
    })
    .controller('homeCtrl', function ($scope) {
         $scope.title = 'This is, the App!';
    })
    .controller('aboutCtrl', function ($scope) {
         $scope.title = 'About App!';
    });
```

### .htaccess

```
<ifModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
    RewriteRule ^ - [L]
    RewriteRule ^ index.html [L]

</ifModule>
```

### console.log (`http://localhost/myngapp/ || http://localhost/myngapp/about`)

[image: console.log dump]

Comment: What happens if you redirect to /about? Do you see the about.html?

Comment: You are going to want to wrap that `html5mode` in a check for browsers that do not support the HTML5 history API. [Supported Browsers](http://caniuse.com/#search=history)

Comment: @Malkus You're right, I will do checks with modernizr and polyfill with history.js. It has a hashbang fallback for HTML 4 browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solved: `<base>` was the culprit

```
<head>
  <script>
    document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');
  </script>
</head>
```

*OR*

```
<head>
  <base href="/myngapp/">
</head>
```

Comment: I was literally just about to tell you that you're going to need to put a `RewriteBase` directive. It looks the same effectively, in your .htaccess just put it at the top (after the `RewriteEngine On`) to get `RewriteBase /myngapp/ #rest of code#`